# Activity indicator should be displayed when navigating from UITableView1 to UITableView2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, activity-indicator

I want to display an activity indicator when navigating form one UITableView1 to another UITableView2 and stop when the table is completely loaded.

I am using XML parsing to get the cell content of UITableView2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following code may help you...

in .h file of UITableView2:

declare variable

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *progressInd;
```

create property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *progressInd;
```

and declare method

```
- (UIActivityIndicatorView *)progressInd;
```

in .m file of UITableView2:

```
@synthesize progressInd;
```

define this method (adjust x,y,width,width position)

```
- (UIActivityIndicatorView *)progressInd {
if (progressInd == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-15, self.view.frame.size.height/2-15, 30, 30);
    progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [progressInd startAnimating];
    progressInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    [progressInd sizeToFit];
    progressInd.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

    progressInd.tag = 1;    // tag this view for later so we can remove it from recycled table cells
}
return progressInd;
}
```

in `- (void)viewDidLoad` method where your parsing starts

```
[self.view addSubview:self.progressInd];
```

use following line where your parsing ends

```
[self.progressInd removeFromSuperview];
```