# iPhone xcode - Activity Indicator with tab bar controller and multi table view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, activity-indicator

I've looked for a tutorial and can't seem to find one for a activity indicator in a table view nav bar. in my mainWindow.xib I have a Tab Bar Controller with 4 Tabs controllers each containing a table view. each load JSON feeds using the framework hosted at Google.

In one of my View Controller I can add an activity indicator to the nav bar by using:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndcator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
[activityIndcator startAnimating];
UIBarButtonItem *activityItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndcator];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityItem;
```

however and can turn it off by using:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = FALSE;
```

But if i place this in my viewDidLoad event it shows all the time. I only want it to show when I select a row in my table view. so I added it at the top of didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the stop line after I load a feed. it shows but takes a second or two and only shows for about half a second.

is the an event that firers before the didSelectRowAtIndexPath event a type of loading event? if not what is the standard menthord for implementing such functionality?

Comment: Do You want to display the activity indicator for parsing action of the rss feed?

Comment: Yes, normally takes about 2 - 3 seconds to move to the parsed feed data.

Comment: I think You have not displayed the activity indicator in the view where parsing is done,don't put the activity indicator in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath instead put it in the viewDidLoadof the view where parsing is done and remove the indicator once parsing is completed

Comment: This is nothing to do with `Xcode` - Xcode is just an IDE - you're probably talking about the `iPhone SDK`, `Cocoa Touch` and `Objective C`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153653/activity-indicator-shold-be-displayed-when-navigating-from-uitableview1-to-uitabl) helps You.This explains to  display the activity indicator for parsing action of the rss feed.

All the best.

Comment: kind of. But I need to start the activity indicator in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. I load it with top level rows, then when one is selected it goes off and loads my JSON feed for the selected row which take 2 - 3 seconds to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In .h file

```
 @property (nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

In .m file,
@synthesize spinner;   // also release in dealloc

In viewDidLoad, do this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndcator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]    
       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
self.spinner = activityIndicator;
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES; // this is the default, but never hurts to be sure
UIBarButtonItem *activityItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:spinner];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityItem;
```

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, do this:

```
 [self.spinner startAnimating];
```

When feed is done, do this:

```
 [self.spinner stopAnimating];
```